# Load from JSON is not working with Patterns in the latest version of Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

When am trying to load the JSON data onto the canvas, every shape is getting loaded but the patterns that are filled in the shapes are loaded only after I click on the shape.

Could some one please explain why this is happening? I even checked this:

```
canvas2.loadFromJSON(json,canvas2.renderAll.bind(canvas2));
```

Also, the same problem is with the `clone()` function: the object is duplicated. But the pattern filled in the object is shown only after I click on the object.

I am using version 1.3.7.

Comment: This is a known issue - but there is no issue on github. Can you please create a issue on  github:https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/new

The issue #903 (https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/903) is similar to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a "temporary" solution, and it works for me in IE9 and google chrome.

My solution is delay the renderAll() of the canvas object right after the loadFromJSON() function is called.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    canvas.renderAll();
}, 1);
```